# Singleton causing memory leaks

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, singleton

so I have a singleton game class like so:

```
class GameScene
{
public:
    ~GameScene();

    static GameScene& GetInstance()
    {
        static GameScene instance;
        return instance;
    };

    void MainMenu();
    void Gameplay();
    void GameOver();

    Sprite Sprites;
    Text* aText[2];
private:
    string MenuText[4];
    TextLabel* m_pText[5];

    GameScene();
    GameScene(const GameScene&) {}
    GameScene& operator=(const GameScene&) {};
};
```

**Note that I am no expert with Singletons and this is my very first time using this particular design pattern.**

The purpose of the class above is to avoid having to instantiate multiple game objects in main.cpp and just use one singleton instance that can refer to all these different objects. This is how I'm defining the class:

```
#include "GameScene.h"

GameScene::GameScene()
{
    m_pText[0] = new TextLabel("arial.ttf");
    m_pText[1] = new TextLabel("arial.ttf");
    m_pText[2] = new TextLabel("arial.ttf");
    m_pText[3] = new TextLabel("arial.ttf");

    // Do stuff with MenuText etc...
}

GameScene::~GameScene()
{
    // This is not being called :( 
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        delete m_pText[i];
        m_pText[i] = nullptr;
    }
}

void GameScene::MainMenu()
{
    // Display some texts... 
}

void GameScene::Gameplay()
{
    // Display some texts...
}

void GameScene::GameOver()
{
    // Display some texts...
}
```

Finally, not sure how relevant this is, the problem may already seem obvious to some of you, but here's an example usage in main.cpp:

```
// Global Objects
GameScene* Manager;

// ...
// In a start up function()
Manager->GetInstance().aText[0] = new TextLabel("arial.ttf");
    Manager->GetInstance().aText[0]->Scale(0.2f);
    Manager->GetInstance().aText[0]->Color(glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
// ... 

// Finally in the render() function
// ...
if (IsPlaying)
    {
        GameManager->GetInstance().Sprites.Render();
        GameManager->GetInstance().aText[0]->Render();
        // ...
    }
```

Example of Memory leaks I am having:

```
{295} normal block at 0x08A668F0, 44 bytes long.
 Data: <    pn          > F0 E4 86 04 70 6E A6 08 F0 E4 86 04 01 00 CD CD 
{294} normal block at 0x08A66DC0, 44 bytes long.
 Data: <Pu  8r   l      > 50 75 A6 08 38 72 A6 08 08 6C A6 08 00 00 CD CD 
{293} normal block at 0x08A66840, 44 bytes long.
```

Note: I know that I should be deallocating "aText" at some point, but the problem is not just a memory leak from aText array. I am getting hundreds of memory leaks (even though I'm not even allocating that much memory at all) and it definitely has something to do with the static instance. Any simple way to fix this issue? Thank you.

Comment: use `unique_ptr` + ditch that manager, call the singleton directly `GameScene::GetInstance()`

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in destructor ?

Answer (score 0):

Your static instance is constructed when you first call `GameScene::GetInstance`, but

> Destructors (12.4) for initialized objects of static storage duration
>   (declared at block scope or at namespace scope) are called as a result
>   of returning from main and as a result of calling exit (18.3).

So, your memory leak checking code may report memory leak even if there are none. Just destructors haven't been called yet.

Example code that missreports memory leak:

```
#include <memory>

#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <crtdbg.h>

class A {
public:
    A() : pi(std::make_unique<int>(0)) {}
    std::unique_ptr<int> pi;
    static void CreateInstance() {
        static A instanceFunction;
    }
};

void main() {
    _CrtMemState initialMemoryState;
    _CrtMemCheckpoint(&initialMemoryState);

    A::CreateInstance();

    _CrtMemState finalMemoryState;
    _CrtMemCheckpoint(&finalMemoryState);
    _CrtMemState differenceMemoryState;
    if (_CrtMemDifference(&differenceMemoryState, &initialMemoryState, &finalMemoryState))
        _CrtMemDumpAllObjectsSince(&initialMemoryState);
}
```

**To solve the problem** you could define your static instance as a class memeber not a local variable.

Header file:

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>

class A {
public:
    A() : pi(std::make_unique<int>(0)) {}
    std::unique_ptr<int> pi;
    static A& GetInstance() {
        return instance_;
    }
private:
    static A instance_;
};
```

Cpp file:

```
#include "A.h"

A A::instance_;
```

**Another solution** is to use `Init`/`Shutdown` pair.

Comment: How about Scott Meyer's singleton?